# Plugin que aplica zoom quando passar mouse

Tags: jquery, plugin

Tenho uma página interna de produtos, o qual o layout está como abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que preciso é que, quando a pessoa passe o mouse em cima do quadrado menor, ele mostre a imagem grande em cima e aplique um zoom quando a pessoa passar um mouse em cima da imagem grande. Estava analizando o plugin `cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js`, porém ele é pago. Alguém já utilizou algum parecido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma breve pesquisa no Google me devolveu bons resultados:

- **Elevate Zoom**: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples - Zoom interno e externo, diversas customizações de posicionamento de divs, customização do cursor durante o zoom, zoom com a roda do mouse, etc. Licença Dual MIT e GPL.
- **Easy Zoom**: http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/ - Plugin simples com zoom em *overlay* e externo. Licença MIT.
- **SwinxyZoom**: http://www.swinxyapps.com/pages/apps/swinxy-zoom/ - Plugin para Zoom interno, externo, lente e arrastando o mouse (todos com controle externo de ampliação). Licença comercial (**£4.00**) ou Creative Commons não comercial com atribuição.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu estava procurando por algum termo que me levava apenas àquele plugin que era pago. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Pra não tornar essa pergunta baseada em opinião de qual plugin usamos, irei mostrar um exemplo:

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [Zoom do Jack Moore](https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom/), existe uma [documentação aqui](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)

**Código Fonte do meu exemplo:**

**jQuery:**

```
$( '.smallPicture li img' ).hover(function(){
    src = $(this).attr("src");
    $( '.bigPicture img' ).attr("src", src);

});
$( '.bigPicture img').hover(function(){
    src = $(this).attr("src");
    $('.bigPicture').zoom({url: src});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bigPicture">
    <img src=""/>
</div>
<br/>
<ul class="smallPicture">
    <li><img src="http://www.internationalrivers.org/files/styles/600-height/public/images/campaign/admin-old/amazon.jpg?itok=rz1JSSBO" height="90" width="90"></li>
         <li><img src="http://www.funonthenet.in/images/pics/wildlife_in_the_amazon/20_wildlife-amazon-two-blue-poison.jpg" height="90" width="90"></li>
              <li><img src="http://rack.1.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE0LzAyLzEwL2VkLzEuQW1hem9uRGFuLjhjODAxLmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/4376b016/1e6/1.-Amazon-Danbo.jpg" height="90" width="90"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bigPicture{
    display: block;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}

.smallPicture li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-height:90px;
    max-width:90px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

Exemplo online: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronnyamarante/1o4g8vow/)**

> **CUIDADO:**   A Zoom apenas aceita: `<a>`, `<span>`, `<li>`, `<div>`. Isso
>   quer dizer que não funcionará em elemento `<img>`.