# Zoom na imagem (abrir ela maior quando clicar)

Tags: javascript, html

Queria dar zoom na imagem mais tem que abrir ela maior quando clicar se tiver como fazer isso?

Código:

```
        <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="compra1.png" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comprar">Comprar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Aqui tem exemplos para o zoom http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28670/plugin-que-aplica-zoom-quando-passar-mouse

Comment: Tentei usar o EasyZoom mas da este erro: http://prntscr.com/divtrw

Comment: Esse erro provavelmente é pq não incluiu o arquivo js do EasyZoom ou usou ele antes de incluir.

Comment: Consegui fazer o de passar o mouse funcionar, mas como que adiciona a função de quando clicar abrir um "popup"?

Comment: Aqui tem exemplos, mas você tem pode procurar por outros plugin que tenham as duas funcionalidades. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023199/bootstrap-open-image-in-modal

Comment: Não tem em popup tipo na mesma página sem abrir outra

Comment: O link que mandei tem exemplos que abre no modal, na mesma página. http://jsfiddle.net/6CR2H/1/

Comment: Copiei o código todinho, coloquei o script mais quando eu clico minha página vai para cima

Comment: isso acontece quando há # no href="#". Tente usar href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: tem esse código muito bacana https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/y6q5a7ha/  do Rafael Boschini

Comment: Recomendo o uso da [Jquery Fancy Box](http://fancybox.net/howto)